# Generating Double pulse using Tektronics Function generator AFG31000

Tags: mosfet, measurement, semiconductors, function-generator, switching-losses

I have Tektronics AFG 31000 function genertor with built in double pulse test app. I want to generate two pulses for my double pulse test but this so simple task is becoming a mountain to climb for me. So I want to trigger these two pulses manually but when i load the pulses and connect ossiloscope, there is nothing which i can see over scope but for same pulses when i change trigger option from manual to timer and sync it wth ossiloscope, i can see stream of pulses with duration and delay i have selected but for my DPT setup, i need only two pulses. Its my first time with this function generator. can anyone please assist me here? Thanks[image]